# Where does breakpoints stores

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, where do the breakpoints store?

When I relaunch VSCode, those breakpoints still exists, so there should be a place for VSCode to store them. But it is stored neither in the workspace, nor in `.vscode`.

I need to know where they store so that I can backup/restore/add/modify/delete multiple breakpoints conveniently and efficiently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Where are the breakpoints stored?

On Windows, the breakpoints are stored in:

```
%APPDATA%/Code/User/workspaceStorage/(long_hash)/state.vscdb
```

On Linux, they are in (per Matt's comment):

```
$HOME/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage/(long_hash)/state.vscdb
```

To locate the `(long_hash)`, I added a breakpoint and looked for a file that was recently modified.  If you have [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) bash, a command like this works, right after adding or removing a breakpoint:

```
  $ cd $APPDATA/Code
  $ find . -mmin -1
```

The `state.vscdb` file is a [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html) database.  I'm able to pull some data out of it using `strings` (another Cygwin command):

```
  $ strings state.vscdb | grep 'debug.breakpoint'
  debug.breakpoint
  debug.breakpoint
  debug.breakpoint[{"enabled":true,"uri":{"$mid":1,"fsPath":"d:\\wrk\\learn\\vscode\\cpphello\\helloworld.cpp","_sep":1,"external":"file:///d%3A/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello/helloworld.cpp","path":"/D:/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello/helloworld.cpp","scheme":"file"},"lineNumber":12},{"enabled":true,"uri":{"$mid":1,"fsPath":"d:\\wrk\\learn\\vscode\\cpphello\\helloworld.cpp","_sep":1,"external":"file:///d%3A/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello/helloworld.cpp","path":"/D:/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello/helloworld.cpp","scheme":"file"},"lineNumber":13}]g
  debug.breakpoint[{"enabled":true,"uri":{"$mid":1,"fsPath":"d:\\wrk\\learn\\vscode\\cpphello\\helloworld.cpp","_sep":1,"external":"file:///d%3A/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello/helloworld.cpp","path":"/D:/wrk/learn/vscode/cpphello/helloworld.cpp","scheme":"file"},"lineNumber":12}]
```

The above is with a single breakpoint at `helloworld.cpp` line 12.

### Is accessing this file a good idea?

Probably not!

If your goal is to query or manipulate the breakpoints yourself by modifying this file, I'd caution that that risks corrupting VSCode's internal storage (even if using a proper SQLite client).

I recommend instead using the VSCode extension APIs [`debug.breakpoints`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug.breakpoints) and [`debug.addBreakpoints`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#debug.addBreakpoints) to query and modify them from within VSCode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And your suggestion really what I need.

Comment: @ChenTian You're welcome!  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Note that on linux (i'm using Archlinux) it is under ~/.config/Code/User

Answer (score 0):

On mac, it's

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/<hash>
```