# Why Jest unit test debugging doesn't stop at breakpoints in Chrome inspector?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, google-chrome-devtools

Unit testing is very helpful and usually makes debugging easier, but only if your debugging tools work properly. I have worked in few `React` project and most of the time the Chrome debugger works well, but sometimes it refuses to stop on a particular breakpoint. Then I manually write `debugger;` instruction in the source code where I like the execution to stop and it usually works. Sometimes even this solution doesn't work and I'm forced to use old fasioned debugging methods like `console.log()`. Currently I have all these issues in a `React` project written in `Typescript` within `Ubuntu 16.04` development environment. They makes debugging very difficult. I start the unit test with `yarn test:debug` command, where `test:debug` calls the following line inside `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect test --runInBand --no-cache"
}
```

I'm new to `Typescript` and am working on a legacy project which is not very well maintained. Could it be a matter of wrong configuration. Maybe something to deal with `webpack`? The debugger's console indicates that a mapping file is missing:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for 
file:///path/to/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js.map: System error: 
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Could it be that missing file the reason for the issues I experience? How to provice debugger with that missing file?

`package.json` dependencies:

```
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.4",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
"@capacitor/app": "^1.0.2",
"@types/fs-extra": "^9.0.3",
"@types/jest": "24.0.18",
"@types/node": "12.7.12",
"@types/node-cron": "^2.0.3",
"@types/react": "16.9.5",
"@types/react-dom": "16.9.1",
"@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
"@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.5.0",
"global": "^4.4.0",
"import": "^0.0.6",
"jetifier": "^1.6.6",
"react": "^16.10.2",
"react-clock": "^3.0.0",
"react-dom": "^16.10.2",
"react-player": "^2.7.2",
"react-qr-code": "^2.0.2",
"react-rating": "^2.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
"react-simple-keyboard": "^2.0.15",
"react-toast-notifications": "^2.2.5",
"ts-node": "^9.0.0",
"typescript": "^4.3.5"
```

`node` version

```
v14.15.0
```

I wonder if any of you has experiend similar issues in unit testing with `Jest` and Chrome inspector and if so could you give me any advise how to resolve it? Could it be some sort of libraries incompatibility or any particular configuration in `React` project?

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth deleting all the saved breakpoints. This worked for me [Where does breakpoints stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767800/where-does-breakpoints-stores)